# How to save QVariantMap into QSqlDatabase

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I've already got an infrastructure to work with. There is an insert function given with the following signature:

```
insert(const QString& key, const QVariant& value)
```

Within the function the `QSqlQuery` is getting prepared:

```
QSqlQuery query{mySqlDatabase};
QString sql = "INSERT INTO my_table(key, value) VALUES (:key, :value)"
query.prepare(sql);
query.bindValue(ENC(":key"), key);
query.bindValue(ENC(":value"), value.toString());

if (!query.exec()) {
    const auto error = q2.lastError();
    throw std::exception(QString("failed to insert: %1")).arg(error.text()));
}
```

This works for all the insertions used so far, but now I'm trying to insert a `QVariantMap` (which is a typedef for `QMap<QString,QVariant>`, in fact I'm trying to save `QMap<QString,int>` type):

```
insert(g_theKey, QVariant(m_theMap));
```

Upon query execution I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

I was looking for solutions on both the Qt website and here, but haven't found a working solution.

Comment: What kind of field is "value"?

Comment: It is QVariant&

Comment: Hmm, you don't seem to understand me. "my_table" is a table in the database so my question is what type of data is the field "value" of the table "my_table"? The same for "key". In the DB there is no type QVariant

Comment: That expects a string. That part of the functionality is not my concern, because as stated above that function works for other types, but it does not work for QVariantMap.

Comment: What are those "other types"?

Comment: I think I found what was wrong.

According to Qt documentation:
QString QVariant::toString() const - Returns the variant as a QString if the variant has type() String, Bool, ByteArray, Char, Date, DateTime, Double, Int, LongLong, StringList, Time, UInt, or ULongLong; otherwise returns an empty string.

Basically, QVariantMap can't be stringified. So my solution, for now, is to stringify and de-stringify the QVariantMap manually.

Comment: Exactly, is what I was going to point out to you

Comment: For the purpose of serializing QMap object I found this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285889/how-do-you-serialize-a-qmap